# How to replace brackets in string using regex in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, replace

I'd like to remove all occurences of "(" and ")" in a string but the following replace line is throwing up a 'group not terminated' error.

```
str = "1+((x*(2*3))+10)";
console.log(str.replace(//(/gi,"");
```

How should I do this?

Comment: If you want to match/replace all "(" and ")" characters, you can simply use [`\(|\)`](https://regex101.com/r/jlCLdM/1).

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please [**search**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+replace+parenthesis) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 0):

A '(' character has special meaning in RegEx (start of Group), you must escape the parentese like this:

```
\(
```

The same for an end parentese. Alternatively you can use a character Group like this:

```
[()]+
```

That will select any character in the Group (in this case parenteses) on or more times.

Comment: What is a `parentese`?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing a character class containing both opening and closing parentheses:

```js
var str = "1+((x*(2*3))+10)";
console.log(str.replace(/[()]+/gi,""));
```

```
1+x*2*3+10
```

But, it is not clear *why* you would want to do this, because most likely removing all parentheses would change the value of the expression.